# How to setup Qt Creator to use windeployqt?

Tags: windows, dll, qt5, qt-creator, windeployqt

I am trying to compile my code in Qt Creator on Windows, and it compiles and runs in Qt Creator. However, when I try to run the exe from outside Qt Creator, I get errors about missing dlls.

From what I've researched so far, there are two options:

1. Find these missing DLLs and copy them into the same directory as the exe, and hope to god I copied the right versions.
2. Use windeployqt to automate (1).

Now I don't want to be dealing with windeployqt via the command line - is there a way I can get Qt Creator to take care of that for me? So far, when I click on `Deploy`, it just builds the project, but doesn't seem to do anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `windeployqt` with `QMAKE_POST_LINK`. Just set `DEST_DIR` to where you want to deploy your application and call the `windeployqt` on that directory.

Here is an example.

```
win32 {
DESTDIR = $$PWD/bin
QMAKE_POST_LINK =  windeployqt $$shell_path($$DESTDIR/$${TARGET}.exe)
}
```

With this implementation, it will create a `bin` folder in project folder, copies the target (.exe) to that directory and runs `windeployqt` on it. You are free to choose another directory relative to your project directory or an absolute path.

Comment: Thank you, this works! For DESTDIR, ideally it would go into wherever the Release build target is set. I could hardcode it, but I think there should be a variable defined for that. I can't seem to find anything about that here though: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html

Comment: @EnterDisplayNameHere You will need to do that. You need to hardcode your deploy path somewhere. It can be relative to any directory like what you do with DESTDIR.

Comment: Man, I love you. Honestly. Thanks for this... what about other platforms? Linux? Mac? Thanks a lot.